# Using IpcRenderer in a Visual Studio Code Extension leads to a Cannot read property 'send' of undefined exception

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, electron, vscode-extensions

I am trying to follow the [electron documentation](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-main) to have a Visual Studio Code extension communicate with a server that processes the request. As a test I attempted the following:

```
const { ipcRenderer } = require('electron');
ipcRenderer.send('d39ca3b2-e0a4-4304-a9a6-faa0f0dba6fe','test');
```

I also added electron as a dependency to the extension's package.json file:

```
"dependencies": {
        "electron": "^9.1.0"
    },
```

This fails at runtime with the following error: "Cannot read property 'send' of undefined". Is the extension's sandbox environment preventing the use of IPC channels? Is there a better way of achieving something like this, i.e. have the extension send a request to some backend/server process?

Comment: Add `nodeIntegration: true` while you are creatin browserWindow

Comment: But what if the extension never creates a window or a webview? For example if you were just extending a TreeView?

Comment: Well, where you are using this ipcRendere then?

Comment: In a custom TreeDataProvider class.